# Beginner question, linear algebra over $\mathbb Z_2$. Xor forward and backward transform.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, finite-fields, boolean-algebra

Being an electrical engineer, I have mostly worked in continous domains with $\mathbb R, \mathbb C$ as fields for elements of functions as well as matrices. Now this question relates to operations in $\mathbb Z_2$

Consider the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix} \text{ it has inverse } A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\-1&1&1\\1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

or over $\mathbb Z_2$:

$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

If we multiply together using normal matrix multiplication :

$$AA^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}3&2&2\\2&1&2\\2&2&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}(\text{mod } 2) = I$$

Which seems to work.

So if I have three bit number $x_1x_2x_3$, stuff it into a vector and then letting $\oplus$ denote addition modulo 0 (or in logics and electronics language "xor") do $$\cases{{\hat x_1}=x_1\oplus x_2 \oplus x_3\\{\hat x_2} = x_1 \oplus x_2\\{\hat x_3} = x_2\oplus x_3}$$

Followed by

$$\cases{{\tilde x_1}={\hat x_1} \oplus {\hat x_3}\\{\tilde x_2} = {\hat x_1} \oplus {\hat x_2}\oplus {\hat x_3}\\{\tilde x_3} = {\hat x_1}\oplus {\hat x_2}}$$

Then we can rest assured thanks to our algebra that we will have:

$$\cases{{\tilde x_1} = x_1\\{\tilde x_2} = x_2\\ {\tilde x_3} = x_3}$$

Is this interpretation correct? Will this approach work in general, just "converting" element-wise inverses we got from doing inverse over a bigger field like we did above.

Comment: Your interpretation seems fine to me.

Comment: The fact that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have integer entries means that you can reduce modulo any number, and the result will still hold. As another example, if you had two integer matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB = 8I$, then you can reduce that equation modulo 7 to show that $A$ and $B$ are inverses modulo $7$.